# Comparar arrays en php

Tags: php, array

Tengo dos arrays en php; el primer arrray se va armando en base a números al azar y puede tener hasta 99 posiciones, el segundo array solo tiene 14 posiciones. Necesito comparar el primero con el segundo hasta que todos los datos del primer array se encuentren en el segundo array y así devolver un `TRUE`, no se si me explico bien. Dejo dos ejemplos, por si acaso.

```
array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 15 [2] => 21 [3] => 27 [4] => 30 [5] => 36 
[6] => 39 [7] => 46 [8] => 51 [9] => 52 [10] => 55 [11] => 62 [12] => 64 
[13] => 80 [14] => 81 [15] => 82 [16] => 87 [17] => 88 [18] => 90 ) 
//primer array, que se forma al azar

//Segundo array, solo tiene 14 posiciones
array ( [0] => 67 [1] => 89 [2] => 8 [3] => 35 [4] => 39 [5] => 54 
[6] => 98 [7] => 73 [8] => 13 [9] => 72 [10] => 46 [11] => 60 
[12] => 26 [13] => 9 [14] => 23 )
```

Agradecería una respuesta gracias

Comment: Sería mejor ver cómo vas creando los arreglos y saber qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer con ellos. En los comentarios de la respuesta mencionas que es un _bingo_, vendría bien que edites la pregunta para agregar esa información, junto con tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$arr = array();
$arr2=array(23,45,23,56,76,45,12,34,45,56,67,78,23,43);

for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
  array_push($arr,$i);
}

function verificar($arr,$arr2){
  // contador
  $contador=0;
  // recorremos el arreglo 2
  // 14 ciclos es mas rapido que 100
  foreach($arr2 as $val){
    //validamos que el valor exista dentro del arreglo 
    if (in_array($val, $arr)) {
        // aumentamos en 1 el contador
       $contador++;
    }
  }
  // retorna true
  // si todos los elementos estan el arreglo
  // ejemplo 14 == 14 //true
  // ejemplo 13 == 14 //false
  return $contador === count($arr2);
}



echo verificar($arr,$arr2) ? "todos estan en el arreglo":"faltan elementos en el arreglo";
```

Comment: Gracias este metodo me funciono

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser interesante el uso de [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php) para este caso:

> Compara array1 con uno o más arrays y devuelve los valores de array1
> que no estén presentes en ninguno de los otros arrays.

Si sólo quieres saber si todos los elementos de `$smallArray`están en `$bigArray`, bastaría con algo como esto:

```
$status = !array_diff($smallArray, $bigArray) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Ahí, `$status` será `TRUE` o `FALSE` según el caso.

Veamos dos ejemplos simples:

**Todos existen:**

```
$bigArray=array (3,15,21,27,30,36,39,46,51,52,55,62,64,80,81,82,87,88,90); 
$smallArray=array (3,15);
$status = !array_diff($smallArray, $bigArray) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

***Salida:***

```
bool(true)
```

**No todos existen:**

```
$bigArray=array (3,15,21,27,30,36,39,46,51,52,55,62,64,80,81,82,87,88,90); 
$smallArray=array (3,15,101);
$status = !array_diff($smallArray, $bigArray) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

***Salida:***

```
bool(false)
```

Otro aspecto que puede ser interesante es que `array_diff` te devuelve un array con los elemento no existentes. Si haces un `var_dump($tatus);` en el último ejemplo, tendrás esto:

```
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  int(101)
}
```

Te mostrará el elemento que no existe en `$bigArray` y el índice que ese elemento ocupa en `$smallArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$valores = array();
$valores2=array(23,45,23,56,76,45,12,34,45,56,67,78,23,43);

$max_num = 99;

for ($x=0;$x<$max_num;$x++) {
  $num_aleatorio = rand(1,100);
  array_push($valores,$num_aleatorio);
}
  echo "</br>";

for($i=0;$i<count($valores2);$i++){
  echo $valores2[$i];
  echo "</br>";
 echo $valores[$i];
  echo "</br>";

      if($valores2[$i]==$valores[$i]){
    
        echo "true";
      }else{

        echo "false";
      }

}

 ?>
```

aqui retorna true cuando los valores coinciden en los primeros 14 espero que sea lo que buscas

Comment: Eso ya intente, el problema es que me devuelve true solo si coinciden las primeras 14 posiciones, y yo necesito completar el array 2 mientras en array 1 vaya armandose

Comment: como vas a comparar el resto de posiciones si ya el segundo termina en el 14 ya el de 99 de 14 en adelante no tendria que comparar mas nada

Comment: solo compara hasta 14 ya que del 14 en adelante no hay mas datos, el otro array no tendria con quien comparar mas posiciones despues del 14

Comment: Claro, no se si nos estamos entendiendo, es para un sistema de bingo, yo tengo un  array con 15 numeros, y cuando voy girando mi bolillero voy armando un array con cada numero que va saliendo, y necesito ir comparando para que los numeros que van saliendo esten dentro del otro array (el que tiene 15 numeros claro)

Comment: quieres llenar el que tiene 14 entonces de forma manual,hasta la posicion 99

Comment: no, el de 14 ya esta hecho, no se modifica, tengo que ir comparando los numeros del array uno con el de 14, sin importar las posiciones, si todos los numeros del array uno existen en el array 2 entoces es true

Comment: para que todos los numeros del array1 coincidan con el array2 por el metodo random es complejo ya que el random muy dificilmente te mostrara los datos de tu array fijo. creo que se deberia dar otro enfoque